# java util UUID vs Hornetq UUID

Tags: java, uuid, hornetq

I am trying to use duplication detection feature in hornetq, to generate UUID, which is the better option, should I choose Java based UUID or UUID generator which comes  with hornetq. what would be the difference

Comment: Either will be perfectly sufficient and extremely unlike to generate duplicate UUIDs (so incredibly small, it's not even worth thinking about or coding a "solution" for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, The HornetQ UUID code is based on an old version of *Java UUID Generator* project http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JugHome https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-uuid-generator/

It has been optimized for high performance (as opposed to optimized to avoid collisions). As you can see in the bug case below, some UUID choices may give you a very slow start-up time (which may or may not be a problem to you).

See more information here https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HORNETQ-854

Comment: I am currently using java UUID.